# PIC 32 interface to Logitech force feedback USB joystick

Tags: pic, usb-host

I am doing a project which requires interfacing the Force feedback USB joystick to a microcontroller, I came across pic32 which has USB hosting capability, now my question is: do I need to develop the device driver for the scratch or can i modify it from the existing to make this work? If so please could you provide the link for the same.

Answer (score 3):

Microchip have various examples that use their [USB stack](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en537044) (comes with all demos and documentation) and work with various drivers that you can adapt. I think HID would probably work for your joystick.

So the answer is, no you (almost certainly) don't have to write your own driver, but you will have to adapt the firmware a bit.

Here is a screen snip of (some of) the host examples I have on my laptop:

[image: USBDemos]